# How to share Realm Result<T> to other view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

How to properly share Realm Result object to other View?

```
final class Transaction: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var buyCurrency = ""
    @Persisted var buyAmount = 0
}
```

```
struct TransactionView: View {
    @ObservedResults(Transaction.self) var transactions
    
    var body: some View {
        EditView(transactions: transactions)
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct EditView: View {
    @ObservedRealmObject var transactions: Results<Transaction>
    
    var body: some View {
       ...
    }
```

I'm having such compilation error:

Generic struct 'ObservedRealmObject' requires that 'Results' conform to 'ObservableObject'

Comment: You need to use [Observed Reslts](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/integrations/swiftui/#views-and-observed-objects)

Comment: You are right. I’m dumb :D